# How could you remove MP3 tags from an existing file

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

I am looking to strip out ID3v1, ID3v2.x tags from an .mp3 file using C#. I would rather not implement it myself - but use something tried and tested.

TagLibSharp looks really good for creating tags - but how could it be used to remove them? If there's any other library more suited to this I'd use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the TagLibSharp RemoveTags() method.

```
file.RemoveTags(tagtypes);
```

where tagtypes is a TagType bitmask for the tags you want to remove.  For Id3v1 and Id3v2, try

```
file.RemoveTags(TagTypes.Id3v1 && TagTypes.Id3v2);
```

Comment: That should be a bitwise or `|` between the tag types.

Comment: You also need to save changes after removing tags `file.Save()`;