# taglib How can I stop ID3 tags from automatically being written?

Tags: c#, vb.net, taglib-sharp

I'm using taglib to remove ID3 tags from my files. Every time I erase all the ID3v2 tags ID3v1 tags are created and vise versa. Basically I don't want any ID3 tags. I wanted the user to pick whether they wanted ID3v1, ID3v2 or None. Do you have any suggestions on how to get taglib to stop automatically creating tags?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found that some other people had a similar issue and one of them found a solution in using the RemoveTags() method.

file.RemoveTags(tagtypes);

Where tagtypes is a TagType bitmask for the tags you want to remove. For Id3v1 and Id3v2, try,

file.RemoveTags(TagTypes.Id3v1 && TagTypes.Id3v2);

taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750002/how-could-you-remove-mp3-tags-from-an-existing-file/16750044#16750044)

Comment: Yeah that's how you remove tags. Thanks though,